# Difference between final variables and compile time constant

Tags: java, compile-time-constant

What is the difference between final variables and compile time constants?

Consider the following code

```
final int a = 5;
final int b;
b=6;
int x=0;
switch(x)
{
     case a: //no error
     case b: //compiler error
}
```

What does this mean? When and how are final variables assigned a value? What happens at run time and what happens at compile time? Why should we give switch a compile time constant? What other structures of java demands a compile time constant?

Comment: Please refer the link to this particular part of topic in JLS

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is, that **all `case:` statements must be ultimate** at compile time.
Your first statement *is ultimate*. `a` will for 100% be no other value than `5`.

```
final int a = 5;
```

However, this is *not guaranteed* for `b`. What if there would be an if-statement around `b`?

```
final int b;
if(something())
   b=6;
else
   b=5;
```

Answer (score 7):

> What does this mean?

It means that 'b' isn't a compile time constant expression, and the JLS requires it to be.

> When and how are final variables assigned a value?

Formally, when the assignment statement or initializer is executed.

But in practice, if the `final` declares a compile time constant the expression is evaluated at compile time and its value is hard-wired into the code.

> What happens at run time and what happens at compile time?

See above.

> Why should we give switch a compile time constant?

Because the JLS *requires* it.

It is necessary for the bytecode compiler to check that the switch statement is well formed; i.e. that the values of the switch constants don't collide. It also allows the JIT compiler to generate code that is optimized for the actual values of the switch constants.

> What other structures of java demands a compile time constant?

None that I can think of, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

From compiler point of view you are trying to use a variable b that **might not be initialized**. The switch statement are compiled into **JVM bytecode tableswitch or lookupswitch** which requires that values used in **case statement are both compile time constant and unique.**

```
final int a = 4; // compiler is sure a is initialized
final int b;// variable b is not guranted to be assigned
```

e.g.
Although this statement will ultimately initialize b , but compiler can't detect it.

```
if (a < 4) b= 10;
if (a >= 4) b = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

The switch statement needs a constant. As final variables can be delayed initialized and the compiler cannot determine for b that it has a value in the case branch.

Comment: Sure but I still did not get the answer  for my questions

Answer (score 2):

`final int b;` can be assigned once and value is not sure, that will be decided on **runtime** depending on conditions. that is the reason, even if being a **final** variable, it is not **COMPILE TIME** constant although it will be a **RUN TIME** constant and case needs compile time constants.